# Dependency Injection results in a crash, when the connection to a MySQL instance fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

```
// CLASS Startup
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>();
}

// CLASS DbContext
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    // -> Error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
    optionsBuilder.UseMySql(ConnectionString,ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString));
}

// CLASS SomeService
public SomeService(DbContext? databaseService)
{
    // Here should be null
    DatabaseService = databaseService;
}
```

Can I do it so it will pass null for the databaseService when the connection fails? Currently, it fully crashes the application.

EDIT: I havent given enough information about what i actually want to achieve. The code is part of a full server application (-bundle). When the server starts, it should test out all its **capabilities**. It should always try to connect to the MySQL instance, but if it fails, it just doesn't support databasing and has limited features. If it does connect, it is able to use databasing as a feature. I'm using Pomelo MySQL, and this is **not a bug** I'm experiencing, but **more a design-question**.

I have narrowed it down to what I think may be the right solution. How do I check if the database is running BEFORE calling `services.AddDbContext<DbContext>()`;? Is it good to have code that tries to connect to the MySQL server in the ConfigureServices method? Is there a better way? Something like this:

```
// CLASS Startup
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (databaseExistsAndCanConnect) {
        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing null in place of a dependency sounds like a bad idea. You should instead catch these exceptions in a way that makes sense for what you're doing.

Comment: Also, I'd investigate into why the connection attempts fail in the first place. If they do on startup, they probably will any time. It's surely not funny to work with flaky db connections.

Comment: Which MySQL provider are you using? Oracle's ultra-buggy one or the truly open source and well maintained Pomelo? What's the actual, full exception text?

Comment: I'm using Pomelo, and it works great and just as expected. Fact is that I want to catch the exception and not register the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want wo set a null value when connection fail, you can use below code.

```
        public SomeService(DbContext? databaseService)
        {
            if (databaseService.Database.CanConnect())
            {
                DatabaseService = databaseService;                
            }
            else
            {
                DatabaseService = null;
            }        
        }
```

But actually catch the exception may give you more details for troubleshooting.
Below is the connection configuration which may solve the crash.

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=WA116;user=mysql1;password=xxx", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));
        }
```

Comment: This does not work, because the code doesn't even reach the MyService class. It crashes once the DbContext Service is registered.

Comment: @Fabi Well, my testing project doesn't crash even with wrong connection string. Is it that reading connecting string fail?  You could make a fake connection string in DbContext service to see if it crashes ·optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=WA116;user=mysql1;password=xxxxx", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));·

Comment: Which Version of the MySQL connector do you have? I am running Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Version 7.0.0
In this version, when no MySQL server is running, it crashes with the message: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: @Fabi  I also use that one version 7.0 in a .net 6 project.  You could try the ' new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()))' instead of "version autodetect'.